# PRIMARY KEY for MERGE engine don't working?

Tags: mysql

My code :

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE super (id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT);
mysql> CREATE TABLE super2 (id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT);

mysql> INSERT INTO super VALUES(1),(2);
mysql> INSERT INTO super2 VALUES(1),(3);

mysql> ALTER TABLE super ENGINE='MYIsam';
mysql> ALTER TABLE super2 ENGINE='MYIsam'
```

Then I created MERGE Engine table :

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE super_merge (id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT) E
INE='MERGE' UNION=(super,super2);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM super_merge;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
```

Will not the rule of uniqueness?Maybe this is normal .

Why, then, to create a structure of table fields if it does not work?

When I truncate tables super,super2 then table super_merge is empty too!

```
TRUNCATE TABLE super2;
mysql> SELECT * FROM super_merge;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO super VALUES(1),(2);
mysql> INSERT INTO super2 VALUES(1),(3);

mysql> SELECT * FROM super_merge;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
```

Comment: Please read MySQL documentation before you ask questions, it's kinda stupid that other people have to paste excerpts from docs so you can read it. Yes, all of what you said is normal. It is documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explicitly mentioned in the [documentation of the MERGE engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/merge-storage-engine.html):

> Note that column `a` is indexed as a `PRIMARY KEY` in the underlying MyISAM tables, but not in the MERGE table. There it is indexed but not as a `PRIMARY KEY` because a MERGE table cannot enforce uniqueness over the set of underlying tables. (Similarly, a column with a `UNIQUE` index in the underlying tables should be indexed in the MERGE table but not as a `UNIQUE` index.)

A merge table is effectively a unioned view over both tables, so naturally removing items from the underlying table(s) will also remove those items from the merge table (as they never were in the merge table to begin with, but simply in the underlying tables).